# Get Android Context in PCL project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I get the Android context from the Xamarin.Forms PCL project?

I have tried to search stackoverflow but none fit my search.

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and I am  trying to learn accessing custom class for android where I need to have an Android Context

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can access in android project with:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context
```

Comment: Or, if not  using Xamarin.Forms, I believe can use `Android.App.Application.Context`.

Comment: As of version 2.5 Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context is obsolete

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context is obsolete, use instead of Android.App.Application.Context

Answer (score 2):

There is no knowledge about Android Context inside the PCL. You have Access to it only inside Android projects.

If you want your app to behave differently based on the Context in Android applications then you need to abstract this logic by a platform independent interface and access it via a dependency injection container.

I prefer to use the `Mvx` container shipped with [MVVMCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross). 
There is a great tutorial for [Injection of Platform Specific Services](http://slodge.blogspot.de/2013/06/n31-injection-platform-specific.html).